# Comparison of Dropwizard vs Play for JS centric Web Application

Tags: angularjs, playframework, dropwizard

Imagine there exists a backend server that hosts data and exposes them to multiple clients via REST interface (CRUD APIs). We are just one of the consumers of data, and want to create Angular JS based user interface for CRUD operations. Now, the plan is to create Play based or Dropwizard based application, that provides APIs to delegate call to data-server. The client side framework will be primarily in angular js and bootstrap for show-off.

Need suggestions - why or why not to go with play or drop wizard in our context ?

PS: We would code controllers in JAVA due to lack of expertise in scala.

Comment: I think you need to clarify other architectural requirements/constraints before this decision. examples would be: using cookies vs token for authentication, if using cookies you need some level of CSRF protection and more.... Another example is your DI strategy: do you want to setup use and IOC controller like guice or.... Authentication/Authorization is a biggy as well: if you go with play the auth/authz strategy will be different form a servlet/jersey/dropwizard one. We used both, and settled on Dropwizard for back end services and now I am exploring NinjaFramework as a Play replacement.

Comment: Thanks for inputs Sbham. We are also settling on dropwizard.